# How to modify data in a range of a column of cells that are not blank

Tags: vba, excel

![This is the excel file. I want to modify the data in column A which are non blank]

[image]

Comment: Your clear lack of interest in your own question is contagious.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Click in an empty cell in column A

Step 2:
Type things (use your keyboard)

Step 3:
Press the Enter key on your keyboard

Repeat these steps until all blank cells are filled with data.